# How to dynamically add and scale with Private Data Collections?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Scenario:

I have **3 organizations (O1-O3)**. O1 is an org of an applicant and O2/O3 administrate his public and private data shared with them. **O1-O3 have private data shared with each other and O1-O2 have private data shared**. The network is running, collections are already distributed and everything works fine.

When i now want to **add more organizations** (in terms of thousands, O4-O1000) of type applicant (O1)  and each of them should have shared private data with Organization 2 (O2) and Organization 3 (O3), how do i approach this when the network is already live and running? Is it scalable? **How would i add dynamically private data collections between those newly added organizations and the 2 established ones (O2 and O3)?**

I already encountered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288903/hyperledger-private-data-dynamic-access) but it is not a solution to my problem.