# How to scale the fabric network for private data sharing among thousands of users/peers/orgs?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

How to achieve the private data sharing in fabric network :

It should be :

1.)  on user level ?

2.)  on peer level ?

3.)  or on Organisation level ?

My understanding for above scenarios

1.) `user level` : if data is to be shared between two users associated with same peer then the data is stored on the peer(blockfile) which can be read easily.

2.) `peer level` : same problem peers are part of same channel. Data is shared on each peer(blockfile) which can be read easily.

3.) `org level` : creating a new org for every new user registered on the platform and then creating a new channel for private data sharing between two peers? `how practical is this approach in case of thousands of users on the platform?`

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: its probably best to read the comprehensive Fabric docs on Private Data  - to understand how it works. See https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private_data_tutorial.html . It describes the use of private data collections (and how they are formed) and provides an example use case.

Comment: You would use collections when transactions (and ledgers in fact) must be shared among a set of organizations in the blockchain network, but when only a subset of those organizations should have access to some (or all) of the data within a transaction. The organizations themselves usually issue identities (cert/key combo) to their respective users that need to transact (eg via client apps) on the network.

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony  But if I try to share the data with a user associated to the same peer then the data will be in readable form in peer data i.e blockfile. And if the users are from different organisations then a new channel has to be created between them. having thousands of organisation is practical/effiecient?

Comment: hi @PaulO'Mahony i just read your answer. I know how private data works in terms of sharing the data etc. But not in terms of scaling - there is no example/written stuff on this on the documentation webpage. Maybe you can elaborate on this? I posted my question here a few day ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878972/how-to-dynamically-add-and-scale-with-private-data-collections

Comment: @rohit_sethi the user wouldn't have access to the peer (not if proper, org security/security policies are laid down etc).  The other feature (aside from private data already mentioned) that allows developers to secure data is an application-level solution in the form of attribute-based access control (ABAC). Private data and ABAC (eg. implemented using fabric-ca-client - see https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html) together with private data give enough flexibility to model a non-trivial business process without revealing confidential information ..

Comment: ...to that user (who should only be accessing the ledger through a client app, not have direct access to nodes).... There is a good blog that goes through a use case that may be of interest https://www.tooploox.com/blog/hyperledger-fabric-confidentiality-on-the-blockchain.

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony thanks for detailed information but I have a final question regarding number of organisations a network should contain. And it'd be even better if you can explain it with example use cases. Thanks once again...